# While parsing same arguments, sometimes segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

I am writing a C++ program that will read in two matrices from two separate files. It will do things with these matrices eventually but I am having issues parsing the command line options right now. This is how I am being presented the data.

There are a couple different command line variants:

dtype N file1 file2 file3

dtype N M L file1 file2 file3

where dtype can be either int or double, if just N is presented all matrices are NxN, otherwise matrix1 is NxM and matrix2 if MxL, and files 1 and 2 contain the matrices to be manipulated while file3 is where the result will be stored.

I have included what I have written so far below. I am a novice with C++ so please don't be too harsh on your criticism.

The issue is right now if I run this code it seems completely random if it will segfault and I have no idea what could be causing it. I know it could be a pain in the rear to troubleshoot segfaults, I look at other questions on here, but I literally have no other option but to ask for your help as I am at a stand still.

To troubleshoot I compiled g++ with the -g option and ran my program through gdb. I could not replicate the segfault through gdb.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

inline bool exists_test(const std::string& name) {
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat (name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); 
} 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int dtype = 0; // 0 = int; 1 = double
    int M = 0;
    int N = 0;
    int L = 0;
    const char *file1;
    const char *file2;
    const char *file3;

    for (int i=1; i<argc ; i++)
    {    
        try 
        {
            if(i==1){
                if(!((strcmp(argv[1], "int") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[1], "double") == 0))){
                    throw invalid_argument("wrong dtype");
                }else{
                    if((strcmp(argv[1], "double") == 0)){
                        dtype = 1;
                    }
                }
            }else if(i==2){
                M=stoi(argv[i]);
            }else if(i==3){
                if(!exists_test(argv[i])){
                    N=stoi(argv[i]);
                }else{
                    file1 = argv[i];
                }
            }else if(i==4){
                if(!exists_test(argv[i])){
                    L=stoi(argv[i]);
                }else{
                    file2 = argv[i];
                }
            }else if(i==5 || i==6 || i==7){
                if(!exists_test(argv[i])){
                    throw invalid_argument("no such file");
                }else{
                    if(i==6){
                        file2 = argv[i];
                    }else if(i==7){
                        file3 = argv[i];
                    }else if(strcmp(file1, argv[i]) == 0){

                    }else{
                        file1 = argv[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            cout << "error code 1 or this one" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if(N==0){
        N=M;
    }
    if(L==0){
        L=M;
    }

    ifstream thisfile;

    double filler = 0;
    vector<double> readThese;
    vector< vector<double> > matrixA(4, vector<double>(3, 0));

    thisfile.open(file1);

    while (thisfile >> filler )
    { 
        readThese.push_back(filler);
    }

    thisfile.close(); 

    //for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
    //  matrixA[0][j] = readThese[j];
    //}

    cout << matrixA[0][0] << " " << matrixA[0][1] << " " << matrixA[0][2] << " " << matrixA[0][3] << endl;
    cout << matrixA[1][0] << " " << matrixA[1][1] << " " << matrixA[1][2] << " " << matrixA[1][3] << endl;
    cout << matrixA[2][0] << " " << matrixA[2][1] << " " << matrixA[2][2] << " " << matrixA[2][3] << endl;
    cout << matrixA[3][0] << " " << matrixA[3][1] << " " << matrixA[3][2] << " " << matrixA[3][3] << endl;
}
```

The following shows that the output of the program. It doesn't always segfault every other time, it just happened to this time.

```
$ ./a.out int 3 4 1 file1 file2
0 0 0 1.63042e-322
0 0 0 1.63042e-322
0 0 0 1.63042e-322
0 0 0 5.14322e-321
$ ./a.out int 3 4 1 file1 file2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ./a.out int 3 4 1 file1 file2
0 0 0 1.63042e-322
0 0 0 1.63042e-322
0 0 0 1.63042e-322
0 0 0 5.14322e-321
$ ./a.out int 3 4 1 file1 file2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Getting segfault sometimes is indicative of UB somewhere in your code, which doesn't, always, result in segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare

```
matrixA(4, vector<double>(3, 0));
```

which represents a 4 x 3 matrix, but then access the 4-th column

```
cout << matrixA[0][0] << " " << matrixA[0][1] << " "\
     << matrixA[0][2] << " " << matrixA[0][3] << endl;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   here
```

which is inexistent, so you get a segfault. To test out of bounds, you can use [`std::vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), it is slower but throws an [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception if you access out of bounds. Once you make sure the code is fine, you can reverse to `operator[]`.

BTW, in general it's a bad idea to represent a matrix as a `vector<vector>`. It's way better to use a single vector and map from 1D to 2D coordinates and vice-versa, due to the fact that a single vector guarantees that the elements are contiguously stored in memory hence you have better cache locality.

Comment: How can you keep track of larger matrices in the single dimension? Does the mapping get complicated? I'll see if I can find a reference.

Comment: @user1362058 If the matrix is ROWS x COLS, your map is `(i, j) -> COLS * i + j`. The reverse map is `m -> (m / COLS, m % COLS)` I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Very helpful!

Comment: @user1362058 It's a pity standard C++ doesn't have a `matrix` class. There are high performance libraries though, e.g. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).